# Settings of ManagedExecutorService in Glassfish 4 ignored

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee, glassfish

Before describing my problem I wanted to outline what I want to achieve with my application.

I basically want to download a possibly large number of files with a defined number of max parallel downloads.

I want to run this application on an application server and choose Glassfish 4 for this purpose (I wanted to try Netbeans and the integration of Glassfish is nice, no other reasons really).

First I tried implementing this with an async ejb-method, but to limit the number of parallel downloads I would have to manipulate the ejb container pools and I don't really want to mess with that.

So I thought I could make good use of the Concurrency Utilities for Java EE (JSR 236), in particular the `ManagedExecutorService`.

My code:

```
@Stateless
public class DownloaderBean implements DownloaderService {

    @Resource(name = "concurrent/downloaderExecuterService")
    ManagedExecutorService downloadExecutorService;

    @Override
    public List<Future<Boolean>> executeDownloadTasks(List<DownloadCallable> tasks) {
        try {
            return downloadExecutorService.invokeAll(tasks);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DownloaderBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

The downloading itself works perfect but imposing the limit on the executor is not working for me. (I submitted 200 DownloadCallables and all of them were executed at the same time)

My settings for "concurrent/downloaderExecuterService":

- enabled=true
- threadpriority=5
- longrunningtasks=true
- hungafterseconds=0
- corepoolsize=7
- maximumpoolsize=10
- keepaliveseconds=60
- threadlifetimeseconds=0
- taskqueuecapacity=2147483647

My understanding is that with `maximumpoolsize` I define how many parallel threads the `ManagedExecutorService` is allowed to execute, the `taskqueuecapacity` defines how many threads can be queued for execution.

So there should be 10 parallel downloads with a maximum of 2147483647 in queue, but that isn't working.

Are my settings wrong or am I missing something here?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I've been working with the concurrency utilities recently so would interested to try and help you with this, although I may not have the exact answer. To clarify, have you created the ManagedExecutorService via the Glassfish Admin Console? Also, how do you know they all execute immediately? Does DownloadCallable log it's progress?

Comment: I have indeed created the ManagedExecutorService via the Admin Console. I know that they download similtanously because I tried with kind of big files and all were created within seconds und my internet connection totally crashed because of the number of connections. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: are 100% sure that your executor is being used and not the default one (concurrent/__defaultManagedExecutorService)? In one my apps I noticed that it was actually using the default executor instead of my custom one and this has a max pool size of 2147483647, worth checking anyway if you log out the thread details from within the Callable.

Comment: I haven't checked it yet. I will at the next occasion und report the results.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use "lookup" instead of "name" for the injection

```
@Resource(lookup = "concurrent/downloaderExecuterService")
ManagedExecutorService downloadExecutorService;
```